# Java scraping charset issues

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, character-encoding, wikipedia

I'm scraping Wikipedia  pages with **Java** in order to extract information contained within infoboxes.

All works fine, except for the character encoding.
Wikipedia pages use "UTF-8" encoding.

The **Ubuntu** eclipse console uses "UTF-8" as default encoding as well.
However, the eclipse console shows some weird symbols when displaying information scraped. (e.g.:`Smith Â· Ricardo` instead of `Smith · Ricardo`)

This is the function I use to read data (it traverses all descendants of a node and join their text information at the end):

```
private String getTextContent(Node node) {
    String text = "";
    List<Node> children = null;     

    if (isTextNode(node)) {
        return node.getNodeValue();
    }
    else if (!node.hasChildNodes()) {
        return "";
    }
    else {
        children = toList(node.getChildNodes());
        for (Node childNode : children) {
            text += getTextContent(childNode);
        }
    }
    return text;
}
```

I forgot to mention that I'm using the **JTidy** library for scraping.

Comment: Show us some code - do you explicitly specify an encoding when you read the data?

Comment: I did not specify any encoding when I read the data.

Comment: You do know that you don't need to screen-scrape Wikipedia? You can just [download it all](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/)!

Comment: The console might be correctly interpreting UTF-8, but if you've got the wrong encoding when you read the data over the network, then you're going to run into problems.  Does JTidy let you specify the encoding? Or can you supply JTidy with your own `InputStreamReader`?

Comment: @JoachimSauer: I know. But I just don't want.

Comment: @GregKopff: You were right! I've specified the "utf-8" as input encoding for the JTidy library, and now it works fine! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console might be correctly interpreting UTF-8, but if you've got the wrong encoding when you read the data over the network, then you're going to run into problems.

Specify UTF-8 as the encoding for JTidy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Eclipse Project Right Click > Run Configuration>Common tab and check for UTF-8 over there.